# How is this ternary conditional expression executed?

Tags: c++, ternary-operator, operator-precedence

```
int x = 5,y = 10;
bool boolean = 0;
int k = (boolean ? ++x, ++y : --x, --y);
cout<<k;
```

When boolean is 0,it outputs 9, however when it is 1 it outputs 10.I know this is happening because of precedence but cannot exactly figure out how is it happening, please help me understand this.

NOTE:I know I can get the expected output if I use parenthesis,or better write a clean code,I am just using this to understand how compiler would evaluate expressions like these according to precedence.

Comment: it better to use `true` and `false` with boolean

Comment: Read up upon the _comma operator_ and prefix increment decrement.

Comment: And what output would you expect?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg when true it should output 11 and 9 when false.

Comment: please don't ever write code like this.

Comment: that's why you should write readable code

Comment: @MuertoExcobito,giorgi This is just for understanding concepts, definitely won't write this way.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using a full `if` - `else` block when you want to do multiple things in each of the `if` and `else` cases. Also, I find it helpful for readability to put my own parenthesis when dealing with complex expressions, even when I know the operator precedence will do what I want.

Comment: The ternary operator can be used in function invocation, printf and return statements, where the if...else construct is invalid.  Multiple increment and decrements are Undefined Behaviour - different compilers can do as they please - this will be compiler-specific code.  However in this example the result is completely defined : x is assigned to k which is immediately overwritten with the value of y.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`,` has lower precedence than `?:`. Which means that the full parenthesising is:

```
int k = ((boolean ? (++x, ++y) : --x), --y);
```

As you can see, `k` is always initialised to the value of `--y`. It's just that if `boolean` is `true`, `++y` happens before that.

---

When looking for the full parenthesis form of an expression, think of it as constructing the expression tree (where the lowest-precedence operator is at the root).

Find the lowest-precedence operator in an expression, and parenthesise its left-hand side argument and its right-hand side argument. Repeat recursively within the sub-expressions just parenthesised.

Comment: Thanks,your answer helped, can you tell me the steps to parenthesize a particular expression given the precedence, I am not able decide which groups to parenthesize for expressions like this.

Comment: @KaranJoisher I tried expanding the answer accordingly.

Comment: @KaranJoisher Why not just put in the parens to remove all ambiguity:  `int k = (boolean ? (++x, ++y) : (--x, --y));`  Makes it immediately obvious as to which parts go where.  No need to try to figure out the precedence of the operators.

Comment: @AndreKostur I know i can simply get expected output if I overide using parenthesis, I am just trying to understand precedence concepts,what would compiler do if I dont use parenthesis.

Comment: @AndreKostur because not all code you're trying to understand is code that you yourself wrote - and trying this stuff out yourself is a good way to get it to stick in your head, or at least give you a reference that you can go back to when you run into someone else's "cleverness"

Answer (score 22):

Due to the comma operator having the lowest [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), your statement is actually equal to

```
k = (boolean ? (++x, ++y) : --x), --y;
```

That means when `boolean` is `true` you both increase and decrease `y`. The result of the ternary expression is thrown away in both cases and `k` is only assigned the result of `--y`.

It should be noted that this is not undefined behavior, as the comma operator introduces a sequence point.

---

To get the result you expect, you need to do

```
k = boolean ? (++x, ++y) : (--x, --y);
```

<sub>Note that the parentheses around `++x, ++y` is strictly not needed, but it does make the expression clearer.</sub>

Comment: I was wondering if someone was going to talk about the non UBness of the code.  Thanks for that.

Comment: @NathanOliver Well, it *is* kind of important in cases like this. :)

Comment: @NathanOliver You'd deserve UB for writing code like this. I'm not a compiler, I don't want to parse code.

Comment: Isn't the non-UBness due to both `?:` and `,`?

Answer (score 8):

Given the above excellent answers, one should write instead:

```
if (boolean) {
     ++x;
     ++y;
} else {
     --x;
     --y;    
}
int k = y;
```

Because then the code is more **readable** and **clear** in its intent. This will help anyone who has to maintain the code (including the original author!) without anyone having to waste time by asking SO questions or worrying about the precedence of `,` or `?:` or what the logistics of assignment to such a complex expression are. Any modern compiler will optimize both this and the above to the same resulting code

Comment: OP's post is clever use of sequencing, but also the type of "clever" that will cause your coworkers to hate you.

Comment: Can the down-voters please explain why?  Am I missing some crucial pre-optimization opportunity that's so important my code is meaningless?  Please give me one good reason to write an initialization as the OP's.  Or not to as mine.

Comment: People are probably downvoting not because your answer is technically incorrect, but because it is not really an answer to the question. The question is, "how does this code work?" and your answer is "who cares, writing code like that is dumb." I 100% agree, and think this is a useful answer, so I haven't downvoted it. But it is a risk you take when posting these types of answers. You have enough rep you don't have to worry about it. :-)

Comment: _Any modern compiler will optimize both this and the above to the same resulting code_ Not sure about that, code with ternary operators generates faster assembly code (sometimes same) compared to `if`-`else`